# Pipeline Docker Run with exit code '1'

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, devops, pipeline

I'm implement a pipeline with a docker image, this is an Angular 13 app with node 14.15, when I run the pipeline I'm gettin the next error

```
##[error]Docker-exec executed: `sh -c "command -v bash"`; container id: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`; exit code: `1`; command output: `Error response from daemon: Container XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not running`
```

I'm use this current dockefile

```
FROM nginx:alpine

ADD ./dist/xxxxxx /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ENV TZ=America/Santiago
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: @PavanJadda this is all my dockerfile

FROM nginx:alpine

ADD ./dist/xxxxxx /usr/share/nginx/html COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ENV TZ=America/Santiago RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

Comment: Where is your CMD or ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: Please share your Jenkinsfile for the Pipeline

Comment: The `nginx:alpine` image probably doesn't include `bash`.  That's not usually a problem, since the image does include the Nginx server and that's what you usually need.  Where is the `command -v bash` invocation and what is it trying to do?